# How to destroy notification_key without knowing the key?

Tags: android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

Is it possible to remove all registration_ids from a `notification_key` without knowing the notification_key itself?
I only have the `notification_key_name`, because the server did not store the `notification_key`.

I tried a HTTP REMOVE Request without specifying the `notifiction_key` field, but then the response says `{"error":Missing \"notification_key\" field"}`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cancelAll() metohd of notifcation manager.

here is [description](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#cancelAll()) of that method

Comment: I think you missunderstood my question. I want to destroy the notification and the bound reg ids on the google servers via http request from my server using asp.net...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is possible at all. I've been also searching for the functionality to remove all User Notifications. But I think the only way to reset everything is by setting up a new project and deleting the old one in the Google Cloud Console.